# How to make this program ask user to replay game?

Tags: python

I would like to know how to ask a user "Would you like to play again?" and how to loop that so it works.

I have tried a few different things but nothing has worked yet. This is only my 4th day learning code and I decided I wanted to try and make my own mini game. All the code so far is done without looking anything up online and is done through memory of what I have learned the past few days so forgive me if its not the best.

'''
        import random
        import time

```
    user_answer = input("Would you like to try and guess the number the die will roll? : ")


    def guess_number():

        dice_sides = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

        r_roll = random.choice(dice_sides)


        if user_answer == "yes" or "Yes":
            print("Excellent, lets play!")

        else:
            print("Okay, have a great day!")

        user_guess = input("What is your guess? : ")



        time.sleep(1)

        print("The number is.....")

        time.sleep(1.5)

        print(r_roll)

        if user_guess == r_roll:
            print("Congrats! You won!")

        else:
            print("Sorry, you lose....")

   guess_number()
```

'''

Comment: You can use a `while` loop that breaks when user_answer is "no". Logic:  `while user_answer == "Yes"`: (have your `guess_number()` within the loop) after one iteration of the game is done, ask the user if he wishes to continue, record his reply in variable `user_answer`, if he types in anything but "Yes", the control exits the while loop.

Comment: another small suggestion: instead of `if user_answer == "yes" or "Yes":`, you could use `if user_answer.lower() == "yes":`, it'll look cleaner and will account for all kind of variations - 'Yes', 'yes', 'YES', 'yEs' etc.....

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
guess_number()
while True:
    response = input("wanna play again?")
    if response.lower() == "yes":
        guess_number()
    else:
        break
```